# What is the Difference between file_upload() and put_object() when uploading files to S3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using boto3 and trying to upload files. It will be helpful if anyone will explain exact difference between `file_upload()` and `put_object()` s3 bucket *methods* in *boto3*  ?

- Is there any performance difference?
- Does anyone among these handles multipart upload feature in behind the scenes?
- What are the best use cases for both?

Comment: Can you add links to the docs for `file_upload()`?

Comment: AFAIK,  file_upload() use s3transfer, which is faster for some task:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `upload_file` method is handled by the S3 Transfer Manager, this means that it will automatically handle multipart uploads behind the scenes for you, if necessary.

The `put_object` method maps directly to the low-level S3 API request. It does not handle multipart uploads for you. It will attempt to send the entire body in one request.

Comment: great! and then what about `put_object()` method of bucket ?

Comment: The ``put_object`` method maps directly to the low-level S3 API request.  It does not handle multipart for you.  It will attempt to send the entire body in one request.

Comment: If you interrupt `upload_file` while it's doing a multipart upload, will this result in a broken upload? Because only some of the parts are uploaded and integrity checked, will S3 accept the half-uploaded file?

Comment: per AWS documentation: "Amazon S3 never adds partial objects; if you receive a success response, Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket."

Answer (score 6):

One other difference I feel might be worth noticing is upload_file() API allows you to track upload using callback function. You can check about it [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html).

Also as already mentioned by boto's creater @garnaat that upload_file() uses multipart  behind the scenes so its not straight forward to check end to end file integrity (there exists a way) but put_object() uploads whole file at one shot (capped at 5GB though) making it easier to check integrity by passing Content-MD5 which is already provided as a parameter in put_object() API.

Comment: Thanks for adding 5GB limitation ... Is the 5GB limit for zipped file or uncompressed file?

Answer (score 5):

One other thing to mention is that `put_object()` requires a file object whereas `upload_file()` requires the path of the file to upload. For example, if I have a json file already stored locally then I would use `upload_file(Filename='/tmp/my_file.json', Bucket=my_bucket, Key='my_file.json')`.

Whereas if I had a dict within in my job, I could transform the dict into json and use `put_object()` like so:

```
records_to_update = {'Name': 'Sally'}
records_to_update_json = json.dumps(records_to_update, default=str)
put_object(Body=records_to_update_json, Bucket=my_bucket, Key='my_records')
```

Comment: you can use `upload_fileobj` for that as well