# What is the difference between put_object and upload_file for aws ruby sdk in terms of permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am attempting to upload a file into a different users bucket with only write access. I have attempted to use both methods. put_object seems to work while upload_file does not.

Comment: Can you show what error `upload_file` gives you? Do you know what policy your user has for the bucket? Those two methods should use the same permissions I believe.

Comment: @JohnC unfortunately I do not know details other than we have getObject and putObject permissions. The error I am getting for upload_file is PermissionDenied.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [What is the Difference between file_upload() and put_object() when uploading files to S3 using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739415/what-is-the-difference-between-file-upload-and-put-object-when-uploading-fil)
**put_object** will send it all in one put with a 5GB limit.

**upload_file** will do "multipart" uploads if necessary and calls a callback function when done.

I think you need all of these permissions to use upload_file:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
```